# Yii Dependent DropDownList

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

Well, i have the following need:

create 3 dropdownlist with dependencies. My table in db is like
id
name
parent_id

Selecting a category at 1st dropdown, it will able to select her childs at second.. and so on...

ny help?

Comment: Show me your try and I may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for reply.
So, i used ajax to reload page and update dropdown content

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dependent dropdown
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/

Now yiiframework.com works bad, so use GoogleCache for open that page.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.